# Mysql :Need to get unique field of two row on base of a column having two different value

Tags: mysql

I have a database structure like this.

this is just dummy table.

```
studentId | marks | grade |  examId
   1         25      A         23
   1         32      A         24
   2         13      B         24
   2         23      A         25
   2         34      A         26
```

I want to write a query to get the studentId of students who was present in both the exams.
as a result, I should get studentId '1' but not '2' as student with studentId 2 was not present in exam-'23'.

I want studentIds which are present in examId 23 and 24, not any relation with count of records.

Right now I have write this query but it is not best performance wise.

```
SELECT studentId FROM students WHERE examId = 23 AND studentId in (select studentId FROM students where examId in (24) )
```

I am expecting query with better performance.

Ok , final answer as per conversation with Nicollof is

```
SELECT studentId FROM students WHERE examId IN(23, 24) GROUP BY studentId HAVING COUNT(studentId) = 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to tell which exams the students must have participated in (as opposed to the already suggested solutions, including all exams) you could just add a where clause

```
SELECT studentid 
FROM students WHERE examid IN(23, 24) 
GROUP BY studentid HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

where 23 and 24 are the exam ids of the exams you are interested in

Comment: sorry but it will also not work if, by this query studentId '2' also will get selected as it is having examId '24' and record-count > 1

Comment: I see you changed your question... You can change the last part of the query to be `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2`. If you need to check for more exams - then change the value of 2 to whatever the number of exams is.

Comment: but it is still the problem, if studentId is having examId 24,25, then having-Count=2 and examId in (23,24) , will select studentId 2, which should not be selected.

Comment: It wont, cause the where clause filters exam 25. Thus, student2's count will be just 1.

Answer (score 3):

```
select studentId from students 
where studentId in (23,24)
group by studentId 
having count(studentId) >1
```

The where clause filter the result  and then the group by clause applied hence you will get what you wanted.

Comment: sorry, but I want to test that studentId must have examId 23 and 24 both. I have updated the database snapshot.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the rows are unique for the combination of studentID and examID, you can just try this -

```
select studentID from table
WHERE examID in (23, 24)
group by studentID
having count(*) > 1
```

Edited answer to accomodate the examID in (23,24) after seeing the edit in question and comments.

Comment: sorry, but I want to test that studentId must have examId 23 and 24 both. I have updated the database snapshot.